# How to fix no such plan error in Stripe using Vue?

Tags: stripe-payments, vuejs3, vite

I am using the product id from the stripe in vue. But it is always through error. Please guide me where I am wrong.

> IntegrationError: No such plan: 'price_1LGPU4SEBFYnfFduMTxpNhje'

[image]

```
const redirect = async () => {
  const stripe = await loadStripe(import.meta.env.VITE_STRIPE_API_KEY as string)
  stripe?.redirectToCheckout({
    successUrl: window.location.href + 'success=true',
    cancelUrl: window.location.href + '?success=false',
    lineItems: [
      {
        price: 'price_1LGPU4SEBFYnfFduMTxpNhje',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'subscription',
  })
}
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: You should login into Stripe and check that this price actually exists.

Comment: @IVOGELOV i update my question you can check updated screenshot that i am using

Answer (score 1):

This error means the Price (price_1LGPU4SEBFYnfFduMTxpNhje) doesn't belong to your Stripe Account. You can double check by logging in your Stripe Dashboard, pasting the Id to the Search box and see if you can find it.

You can also check your [Request logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs) to find recent errors.

Comment: I update the question you can check the updated screenshot that i am using

Comment: The price in your screenshot and the price you got in your error message is different